# Build a smooth low poly foot stool with lower than 15K Tris / Faces

Tags: modeling

I need to build an Ottoman Footstool for a CG Trader test to qualify to build models for them.  One main requirement is to build the stool with no more than 15K faces / Tris.  The moment I use subsurface modifier my faces become too much.  The same problem is when I create wrinkles with the sculpt tool.  It generates way too much faces!!  Is there a propper effective function in Blender?
Here is the sample of chair - need to be exact.
[image: **Ottoman footstool**]

Comment: Can you use a Bump/Normal map for the wrinkles?

Comment: 15k is a lot for this... what have you been asked to do, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Rob, use Normals. Also, your material will count to fake the texture (put a bit of noise and glossy in it) but it's not the topic here.

- Create a low-poly object, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and *Smooth Shade* it.

[image]

- You could duplicate your object to sculpt a high-poly version, but an even simpler technic is to keep one object and to fake the high-poly version with the *Multires* modifier. So give your object a *Multires* modifier and click *Subdivide* several times (5 times here).

[image]

- In *Sculpt* mode, begin to sculpt all your wrinkles and details.

[image]

- In the *UV/Image Editor*, create a new black image. Unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* mode. Create a material with an *Image Texture*, load the previously created image, but for the moment don't plug the *Image Texture* into the *Diffuse*. Go in the *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Bake*, *Bake Type* > *Normal*, click on the *Bake* button, the normal map will appear on the *UV/Image Editor*.

[image]

- Now duplicate your object with its modifier and keep a copy somewhere. Delete the *Multires* modifier on the original. Plug the *Image Texture* (*Non-Color Data* mode) into a *Normal Map*, plug it into the *Normal* socket of the *Diffuse*. Boom the wrinkles appear on your object as if they were in 3D.

[image]